# Create aggregate function not working in hsqldb

Tags: java, aggregate-functions, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I am trying to create a java language routine for an aggregate function in hsqldb following the syntax given in this page - http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_jrt_aggregate_functions

```
SQL used:
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION TESTFUNCTION(INOUT ARG DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE
    NO SQL
    LANGUAGE JAVA
    EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:com.XXX.tips.TestUtil.HsqlCustomFunctions.TESTFUNCTION';
```

I am using spring jdbcTemplate.execute method to run the sql and I am getting this following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [

nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: AGGREGATE in statement [

CREATE AGGREGATE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
    at 
...
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: AGGREGATE in statement [

CREATE AGGREGATE]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:420)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:395)
    ... 21 more
```

Can anyone help me out here? I do not understand why this is happening. It is weird because it is saying AGGREGATE is an unexpected token but I am following the correct syntax

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of exception usually indicates you are using an old version of HSQLDB. The class names in the stack trace show this is an old version 1.8. Use the latest HSQLDB 2.x.

Comment: Hi fredt, I am using hsqldb-2.0.

Comment: You are certainly using 1.8. It must be somewhere in your classpath. Please use the latest version, 2.2.9 or 2.3.0 Release Candidate

Comment: Try this with the 2.3.0 release candidate.  It's working flawlessly for me. Pretty neat stuff.

Comment: My dependency manager says I have 2.0  version but my classpath has 1.80 jar.. Thanks for the answer.. 
It is amazing that you found the version just by looking at the stack trace.. :)